# Multi browser window drag & drop interface

Tags: javascript, html, user-interface, drag-and-drop, browser

I'm building a control room interface for a web based vehicle tracking system. The system is built in HTML / Javascript / PHP. The control room will have a desktop extended over multiple monitors with a browser window on each monitor.

What I'm trying to implement in a drag and drop system between the windows. As an example:
Window A contains a list of vehicles. 
Window B is dedicated to viewing a single vehicle with live tracking.
The user should be able to drag a link / image / button next to a vehicle listing from window A to window B to display the selected vehicle tracking in window B.

I know this can be done with a click event and the "target" property, but how do I implement the same thing with a drag and drop?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use HTML5's drag and drop events, they work between different browser windows:
http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/dnd/basics/